# Elastic with_position_offsets

Tags: r, elasticsearch, ropensci

I get an error when I execute the following body in elastic in R.

```
{"stored_fields": ["CONTENT.LENGTH"],
                    "_source":["DOC_ID", "DELIVERY_ID", "SRC_SYSTEM", "CONVERS_ID", "CONTRIB_ID", "CONTRIB_TYPE", "PRTCPNT_ID",    "CONTRIB_TS", "LANG", "SYS_NOT", "SURVEIL"],
                    "query": {
                    "bool": {
                    "must": [
                    {', body_search,'}
                    ],
                    "filter": [', body_filter, ']
                    }
                    },
                    "highlight": {
                    "pre_tags" : ["<mark>"],
                    "post_tags" : ["</mark>"],
                    "fields" : {
                    "', curr_search_field,'": {"term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets", "fragment_size" : 200}
                    }
                    } }
```

The error message is

> Error: 400 - [highlight] failed to parse field [fields]

Without `"term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets",` i don't get an error.
How can I fix this? I have Elastic v6.

Comment: did you turn on verbose errors? `connect(errors = "complete")`

Comment: Yes, i set verbose = TRUE and if I execute your command i get  transport:  http 
host:       127.0.0.1 
port:       9200 
path:       NULL 
username:   NULL 
password:   <secret> 
errors:     complete 
headers (names):  NULL

Comment: Did you try connecting with `connect(errors = "complete")`? you should get a more verbose Elasticsearch stack trace than `Error: 400 - [highlight] failed to parse field [fields]`. Also, that JSON above seems invalid.